# .net 7 How to set outputcache expiration from inside the controller?

Tags: outputcache

I need to set the Cache Duration within the controller or set something that can be used by a cache policy to set the `ResponseExpirationTimeSpan`. (How long the data can be cached varies based on the situation)

I am not using minimal API.

I tried setting the expiry value via httpContext and picking it up in a policy. eg.
`HttpContext.Items["cacheExpire"] = 2;`

but

`IOutputCachePolicy.CacheRequestAsync` & `IOutputCachePolicy.ServeFromCacheAsync`
gets called before the controller method and setting it in `IOutputCachePolicy.ServeResponseAsync` does not take effect.

What is the correct solution for this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the cache duration in a controller, get the `IOutputCacheFeature` and set the time on it.

example:

```cs
public class TestController: ControllerBase
{
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult<string> Get()
  {
     var cache = HttpContext.Features.Get<IOutputCacheFeature>() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Output cache feature not found");
     cache.Context.ResponseExpirationTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
     return "Test Controller";
  }
}
```